# Tooltip bootstrap cannot show in edge at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a tooltip boostrap for a div tag at runtime. It work well on Chrome but in Edge it does not work.

```
<div id="@company.Id" class="fit-container pointer_cursor row" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@company.Comment" data-placement="bottom"><.div>
```

At runtime i will add a tooltip for div, but after i added, when i hover on div tag, the tooltip show nothing. Even though i call  `$('div').tooltip()` in javascript.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Its working in all browsers. May be you forgot to add some assets.

```js
$('div').tooltip();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="" class="fit-container pointer_cursor row" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip test" data-placement="bottom">test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. With including popper.min.js